# apachesolr filters do not work

Tags: 6, search

I have installed apachesolr module and built the index for it. now i can search normally but when i filter the result using any enabled filter, the result DOES'T change and i get the same result of searching for the key. for example i searched for `business` and then filtered the result using taxonomy `tid:36` and i got the same result before filtering!!
I have var_dump the $query that has been generated at line 215 in apachesolr_search.module and part of the result is shown below

```
object(Solr_Base_Query)#17 (13) {
  ["id"]=>
  int(1)
  ["fields":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["fields_added":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["fields_removed":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["filterstring":protected]=>
  string(6) "tid:36"
  ["field_map":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["subqueries":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["keys":protected]=>
  string(8) "business"
  ["base_path":protected]=>
  string(24) "search/apachesolr_search"
  ["solr":protected]=>
  object(Drupal_Apache_Solr_Service)#16 (20) {....
```

also the filter doesn't appear in **CURRENT SEARCH** block. the block still showing

```
CURRENT SEARCH
Search found 38 items

(-) business
```

Also I have made a `var_dump` for params array that has been generated in `function apachesolr_search_execute` in apachesolr_search.module at line 212 and the result was:

```
array(13) {
  ["fl"]=>
  string(71) "id,nid,title,comment_count,type,created,changed,score,path,url,uid,name"
  ["rows"]=>
  int(10)
  ["facet"]=>
  string(4) "true"
  ["facet.mincount"]=>
  int(1)
  ["facet.sort"]=>
  string(4) "true"
  ["hl"]=>
  NULL
  ["hl.fragsize"]=>
  NULL
  ["hl.simple.pre"]=>
  NULL
  ["hl.simple.post"]=>
  NULL
  ["hl.snippets"]=>
  NULL
  ["hl.fl"]=>
  NULL
  ["spellcheck.q"]=>
  string(8) "business"
  ["spellcheck"]=>
  string(4) "true"
}
```

nothing for `fq=tid:36`
any idea of what i might be missing? or how to fix it?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Which version of the module are you using?

Comment: latest version:6.x-1.6

Comment: The line 212 in apachesolr_search.module says `function apachesolr_search_execute($keys, $filterstring, $solrsort, $base_path = '', $page = 0, $caller = 'apachesolr_search') {` so there's nothing generated there. Faceting parameters are added only on line 232, so try var_dumping `$params` after that and then refine your question. You even get the `$final_query` only on line 235; that may be worth seeing as well.

Comment: params already var_dumped in the question above.

Comment: Yes they are, only you var_dumped them too early. They change after the stage you var_dump them at. Hence my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using [Search API](http://drupal.org/project/search_api) module, which can handle Solr and facets, and enables you to use Views to create the search page and has a very good UI for creating search index with facets ect.

I've used it several times and have been pleased with the result.

Comment: search_api is for drupal 7.x i have drupal 6.x. also i have tried this module before and it was working fine. but i dont know what is wrong this time :(